# What is the opposite of the word "Not"?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, antonyms, logic

We are working on a technical manual and we'd like to have a word that is opposite to the word **"Not"**.

Generally, the accepted way to address this is to omit the word itself. In this case however, it would be extremely useful to have a clear placeholder word to indicate the absence of **"Not"**.

We've tried **Isn't** but that presents issues with conjugation. We've also tried replacing the word **"Not"** entirely but it doesn't work either.

Comment: (a) There is no opposite to the word _Not_. The word _Not_ **IS** the concept of "opposite". (b) Without some examples of the text you are trying to modify, and some idea of what kind of result you want, your question is impossible to understand, let alone answer reasonably. Language is not engineering, and simple "opposites" do not exist.

Comment: I sense the oncoming of a lot of *not-not* jokes ...

Comment: "Ton", obviously!

Comment: Can you give us some context?  Even if there isn’t a general antonym, there might be a specific one that works for your particular need.

Answer (score 5):

'So' is the opposite of not.

Is it true that geese can fly ?

> 1. No, it is not.
> 2. Yes, it is so.

Comment: It is definitely not an exact antonym.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It is definitely so, an exact antonym. :)

Comment: Nice try but no cigar. And try 'It is not even a near antonym'.